# A language pack isn't available in Windows 10 Pro 64bit

Tags: windows, windows-10, language

In Windows 10 I use a english version with Swedish input method. It works fine. But I can't for some reason add a language pack for the display language in Swedish in:

```
Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Language options
```

**The only message that I get is:**

```
A language pack isn't available
```

**OS:** Windows 10 Pro 64bit

**Current build Number:** 10586

I have all the latest updates compiled and ready. Also a valid product key. I tried this on another machine and it worked to download the language pack. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to manually add the MUI language pack the build 10586 by downloading here: http://winaero.com/blog/download-mui-language-packs-for-windows-10-build-10586/

Then I ran **lpksetup.exe** and added the .cab file and restarted the computer and set the language as the display language. Logged off and logged in again. Success!

Comment: This appears to be a 404 like response to this url.

Answer (score 1):

I know the OP asked for 10586 but for anyone who needs it, the following link provides MUI packs for Windows 10 Creator Version (1703) which caused some of my computers to lose fonts and the "A language pack isn't available" error.

Tested on Windows 10 Version 1703 Build: 15063.413

**[Link is dead]** http://winaero.com/blog/download-mui-for-windows-10-creators-update/

**[Now try this. WARNING: I have not tested it myself.]** https://www.itechtics.com/download-language-packs-windows-10-version-1803/#Windows_10_Version_1803_Language_Packs_Download_Links

Comment: This appears to be a 404 like response to this url.

Comment: @macetw try the new link. Haven’t tested it but looks like the same thing.

Answer (score -1):

I had to go to: `Control Panel\Clock, Language, and Region\Language\Advanced settings` and select `Use language list (recommended)` instead of my local language which seemed to be unavailable. Then, I was able to download the language pack for my language and select it as a `Display Language`.